# knockout: how to raise an event from a view model?

Tags: knockout.js

I have to work with some legacy code and I need this "hack". I have a view model, I need this view model to raise an event so that it can be handled by some other javascript module (NOT a ko binding). Following is my current solution, but I am wondering if there is a more elegant one.

```
var vm = { 
    // I could have used ko.observable().extend({notify:"always"}) here, 
    // but that will require me to pass a dummy value as an arg to raise 
    // an event, which is ugly.
    onDataReceived: new ko.subscribable(), 
    handleSomeButton: function () {  
        // fancy code, fancy code, fancy code
        self.onDataReceived.notifySubscribers();
    }
};

vm.onDataReceived.subscribe(function () {
    // some code that can't be turned into a binding.
    window.alert("Yep, using window.alert to handle VM events, so what?");
});
```

KO version: 3.1.0

**ALSO**
I could use `$.Callbacks`, but I don't want to introduce a similar-yet-different pattern for handling events.

Comment: [ko.postbox](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox)

Comment: @JeffMercado, that's a valid solution, but an overkill in my situation. I _want_ the event to be scoped to an object.

Comment: @THX-1138 So, what exactly are you trying to hook into, the `onDataReceived`, the `handleSomeButton`?  It's not clear what you're after.  Raise *what* event, and upon *what* exactly? Do you have access to *all* of the legacy code? You said to @JeffMercado that you want the event to be scoped to an object.  What object?

Comment: @EricTaylor, I want to raise event `onDataReceived`, in response to some other (possibly async) operation. I do have access to ALL legacy code, but I don't want to change it.

Comment: @THX-1138 I see no [obvious] non-intrusive way to accomplish that.  From where I sit, it seems that you're going to have to modify the legacy code, at least a little bit.  The problem is that `onDataReceived` is scoped to the vm--it's not on a message or event bus. Does the code base at least rely on AMD (say, RequireJS)?